# find which database table is connected by admin panel

Tags: database, extensions

we are using magento extension.

using that extension we are storing values in admin panel.

i want to know what is the database table name the values are storing

Comment: Show your module etc/config.xml file

Comment: please check this : http://pastebin.com/1tti9mYh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per XML might be it is storing in checkdelivery table.

```
<entities>
    <checkdelivery>
        <table>checkdelivery</table>
    </checkdelivery>
</entities>
```

Comment: strange , that that table not exists, thanks a lot for guiding me

Answer (score 1):

Save something unique (random characters) then use phpmyadmin to search for that string.. this will lead you to the table you are looking for.